# i keep getting this.updateFn(...) is not a function everytime i press a button that invokes this.updateFn(...)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular application and I'm trying to invoke the function given below.

```
updateFn: () => (val: boolean) => void;
```

I'm doing it like this:

```
this.updateFn()(true);
```

But it keeps giving me a `this.updateFn(...) is not a function` Typescript error.

Comment: Can you show the *entire* class definition and where you are calling it from rather than just the single lines?  It's not obvious at all why you would be getting this error without a [mcve].

Comment: **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem

Comment: It appears that you have incorrectly tagged an Angular 2+ question as AngularJS but it is hard to tell because the code is so incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

`is not a function` is a runtime error, so it's a JavaScript error, not a TypeScript compiler error as your question suggests.

You have only created a *type annotation* for `updateFn`. You haven't actually given it any value, hence it turns out to be `undefined`.

```
updateFn = () => (val: boolean) => void;
```

The change is the fist `:` to `=`.